# What's a good quick-for-users wiki/cms?

Tags: content-management-system, wiki

What's a good wiki/cms system that's super easy for users?  I'm building an info directory website for public use.  I need a system that makes it quick and easy for users to add pages and modify content.  Remember how craigslist was back in the day (you didn't have to create an account to post)?  Like that!

I've looked at http://www.wikimatrix.org/ but was overwhelmed with options and didn't give opinions and reviews on them.  Hopefully somebody here can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

We've used [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) and found it to be pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dooWikis](http://doowikis.com).  Anyone can us the simple WYSIWYG editor without learning complicated wiki codes.  Plus, you have the option of embedding the wikis into your own website so that there's no third-party branding or domain to deal with.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks easy to use.  I'll check it out.